# Is buying or selling forex, commodities and stock indices halal in Islam?

Tags: sharia, trading

Websites like [eToro](http://www.etoro.com) offer services where you can buy and sell **currencies**, **commodities**(gold, silver, oil, etc.) and **indices**(SPX500, NSDQ100, DJ30, UK100, FRA40, GER30, etc).

It's basically an online trading platform. The way it works is that, for example, you buy *gold* or *euro* at a price from the current market and later sell it for a higher price(if the price goes up). Now, you predict the market and think that euro may rise against dollar or vice versa, which may or may not happen.

I don't know much about Interest or Riba and I wonder if the above trading is Halal in Islam? Detailed answers with authentic references are appreciated.

**EDIT**

The comments to this question convinced me that it was Halal, until I read the following on [eToro](http://www.etoro.com/why-etoro/islamic-account.aspx).

> Both FX and commodities are traded in the spot market for 24 hours. At 5:00 pm New York time, all open positions are rolled over for the next 24 hours and the daily interest is added to the company’s accounts every 24 hours. The company can then either pay the interest or charge the client’s account to cover the fees.
>
> With an Islamic account we make sure that there is no Riba in any form throughout the duration of the contract. In the FX market, if you don't close the trade before 5:00 pm New York time, all open trades will be automatically rolled over, which normally poses a problem for those following Islamic law, due to the possibly usurious interest charged for the rollover.  However with an eToro Islamic account, all your positions will be closed at 5:00 pm (10:00 pm UST) and you can then reopen them immediately in order to avoid all interest problems and trade according to Islamic Sharia law. If the client chooses to reopen a trade immediately, the client will not pay any usurious interest.
>
> There's no doubt that currency trading is one of the most difficult dilemmas in Islamic jurisprudence (Faqih). On the one hand, it requires the simultaneous exchange of currencies,  which makes it a kind of hand to hand exchange. On the other hand, contemporary scholars consider the record of money transferred to or from a bank account as delivery. To resolve the issue, several decisions and fatwas have been issued. According to these decrees, the conditions for trading currency are:
>
> 1. Immediate buying and selling without delay
> 2. The currencies needs to be transferred from the account of the seller to that of the buyer and vice versa
> 3. The cost of the trade should be paid without delay
> 4. No interest on trades. In the case that there is any usurious interest, the contract will be invalid, void and Haram.

Comment: Speculating is a problem, as it is very similar to gambling.  However, if you invest without speculating, that is fine (i.e. you don't just guess, you do lots of research in the direction of the company you are investing in, and not just throwing money because you have a good feeling that the company will do well).  Commodities are also fine, but indices can be risky as they can involve companies which muslims cannot invest in.

Comment: see also:http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/121/is-investing-on-stock-market-haram

Comment: @oshirowanen: changed *speculate* to *predict*.

Comment: his trading in commodity market sepcially in gold, silver , crde oil is haram or hallal
pls clearfy

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE, We suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq). We are glad to have you as part of our community. Please take a look around at highly upvoted questions and answers, as well as the FAQ to get an idea of what we expect here. We typically expect answers to comprehensively address the question that was asked, backed with references and proofs. Once you build up some reputation points, you can leave comments (like this one) on a post.

Answer (score 1):

As you know already interest is haraam, I probably don't need to provide any hadith or quranic verse to prove that.  If I do need to prove this first, please let me know as it won't take long.

Based on your research, I can clearly see that you think the stock market is very difficult for muslims, and you're right, it is!

Based on my own research, here are the problems:

1. The company must not have a product which is forbidden in islam, alcohol, interest based loans etc etc
2. The company must not be in debt, i.e. it must not be paying interest on a loan
3. The company must not be using money from shareholders and sticking that money into an interest based account and earning interest on it

These 3 points rule out most of the stock market...

However, you can still find companies through which you can still get into the stock market in a halaal manner.  For example, HSBC Amanah Freedom Plus accounts, let you do just that.  For example, they have scholars who monitor the funds and make sure they are halaal.  As soon as they are found to be haraam, a particular stock from a fund is removed.  Plus anything related to interest is automatically removed from the funds and given to charity.

For more info, check out this link:
http://www.expat.hsbc.com/1/2/jerseyfundinvestments/hsbc-amanah

I don't know how many of these types of companies there are around the world, this is the only one I have found with a little research.

Answer (score -4):

Assuming the definition of riba is not derived from ra-ba-wa (to grow) as hinted by Allah SWT at 30:39, where by there is no notion of growing in riba, but rather riba would have something to do with ra-ya-ba or uncertainties such as futures, hedging, etc. The abuse of ra-ya-ba to the point of harming others is what i define as riba.

So in the case of futures, as long as it's for the good of others it's ok.
Cases like anticipating a hardship season to come, would be an example of a good for others.
Cases like insider trading would be bad for others and be categorized as riba.

wallahua3lam

Comment: business is all about managing risks (ra-ya-ba or uncertainties), a business that harm others is what i would define as riba

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange.  Unlike a typical internet forum, here we're attempting to build a high-quality library of questions and answers; as such, we typically expect answers to be referenceable.   As written, this post looks like mere personal opinion and should be backed up by evidences or it risks deletion.  See also [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: This post also instigated the following question: [What is the root of ربا?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5627/what-is-the-root-of)

Comment: i did clarify my position:
there are some who hold the opinion that some letters are interchangeble such as ba and meem; ya , waw and alif; etc
such as the usage of bakkah and makkah; etc